# Should we always make every Link/Button atleast 44X44 size in Mobile site, According to iOS Human Interface Guidelines?

Tags: web-app, guidelines, mobile-web, legibility

According to [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Characteristics/Characteristics.html)

> The comfortable minimum size of tappable UI elements is 44 x 44
>   points.

Should we follow this rule for Every link on Mobile Website for better usability?

See this screenshot of http://m.yahoo.com the links in footer are not 44X44.

**my question is should we always make every Link/Button make at-least 44X44?**

[image]

**It's not about 44X44 only it's about making tappable area bigger so user can easily tap with finger. So should we also make every tappable area big enough?**

It's even a best practice for Desktop website which uses Mouse

[image]

Comment: Also found this http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1691-what-is-the-optimal-size-of-an-iphone-touch-target/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a Good answer here [Make sure your finger can hit the target and text is legible.](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/12/07/4-of-10-make-sure-your-finger-can-hit-its-target-and-the-text-is-readable.aspx)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a good rule to follow if the links are part of the content/interface.
but the links on the yahoo website like privacy/help/legal aren't going to be used that much, the user can always zoom in if they really want to click that....

Comment: My thoughts exactly, I know its good practice, but other than maybe help how many users look at the legal / privacy stuff anyway?

Comment: True, webpages are slightly different because of the zoom factor. But, that Yahoo page is the mobile version, so zooming is disabled.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't the 44x44 recommendation for "items in a tool bar" in mobile apps and not websites?

Answer (score 2):

As iOS HIG stated

> The comfortable minimum size of tappable UI elements is 44 x 44 points.

There can be times when you don't want/need tappable UI elements. Just base this decision on your business objectives and user needs. For example: I'd care more about making the page short than making "Legal" easy to tap

EDIT:
Ok. Not just the page length, but also things like reducing visual clutter and creating hierarchy for good information design (e.i. not giving too much focus on what's not too important for the business/user)

Comment: But you can increase the tappable area of Legal without making the page longer. there are enough margin available.

Comment: didn't understood your edit. I just added more padding to increase tappable area here http://i.imgur.com/d68Dn.jpg and It's not adding any visual clutter. I could be wrong though

Comment: I'm not a fan of the 'keep it short' model. Our UX lead does the same thing. I find it's a symptom of designing everything on paper with their little iPhone box mockups. It's INCREDIBLY easy to scroll on a touch device and having bigger targets at the expense of a longer page is MUCH better than having small targets even though everything is on one screen, IMHO.

Comment: @DA01 - I think same

Comment: though I *do* agree with Allan that certain links don't need the same emphasis.

Comment: But if they are not important then they should not on the page. I think every tappable thing on the page should have bigger target so user can tap precisely. 44X44 is for finger

Comment: true. good point

Answer (score 2):

You should ALWAYS follow the rules of good graphic design and user experience. Except in situations where it makes sense to break the rules.

Comment: You should ALWAYS follow the rules except in situations when you SHOULDN'T. I'm sorry, does this make any sense?

Comment: @mojuba yes, it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Even though *some* of those links aren't critical, they're important enough to be there and deserve a good treatment for mobile. Since there's at least one feature that speaks to a personalized list (add to favourites), the Sign In link seems to be an important part of the experience and at minimum should have a touch-friendly size.

Though not critical, I'd recommend going the distance and using the already built elements to make those secondary links touch-friendly, and maybe explore putting them into an expanding list to tidy up the screen space.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to highlight the main buttons on the UI, you should use 44px according Apple's guide.

However, all links that you do not consider important on the footer or the ones that have been chosen by hierarchy, might be smaller than 44px. You just need to be careful about the tap area.